Change the reference tag for nested subfigures
I am using nested subfigures in 4 by 1 configuration where each row has 1 by 2 subfigures as in the figure. However, I need nested subfigure (1,2) numbers in each row in roman numerals and main subfigure (4,1) numbering in English letters.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
% First row (nested subfigures)
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 1b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Row 1 Caption}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1em} % Vertical space between rows

% Second row (nested subfigures)
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 2a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 2b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Row 2 Caption}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1em} % Vertical space between rows

% Third row (nested subfigures)
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 3a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 3b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Row 3 Caption}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{1em} % Vertical space between rows

% Fourth row (nested subfigures)
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 4a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{no-10.png}
        \caption{Figure 4b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Row 4 Caption}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Overall caption for the nested subfigures}
\label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

welcome! could you also explain a bit more clearly what you're trying to do? subfigures aren't designed to be nested, as far as I know. they use a single counter, for example. your question suggests you expect that but want it formatted differently in different places, which it is difficult to make sense of.
